# RInside Callbacks

Tags: r, rcpp, rinside

I try to set some callbacks of RInside but I realise that there is a definition of variable RINSIDE_CALLBACKS which prevents the compilation of function causing a linker error

```
 void RInside::set_callbacks(Callbacks* callbacks_)
```

how can install rinside and force the compilation with RINSIDE_CALLBACKS defined?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how much C / C++ you know but the idiom used in `RInside.cpp`

```
RInside::RInside()
#ifdef RINSIDE_CALLBACKS
    : callbacks(0)
#endif
{
    initialize(0, 0, false, false, false);
}
```

using such an `ifdef` usually depends on a definition being made, either as a compiler option (eg `-Dfoo` would define `foo`) or in a header file.  Which is what we do here in `RInsideConfig.h` :

```
// uncomment to turn on the experimental callbacks
// #define RINSIDE_CALLBACKS
```

Note the comment about experimental, and understand that you will enable "unreleased" and
unsupported code.  If you have time to work on it, great.  If not, well...

Comment: Dirk I know the issue but RInside compiled and installed by RStudio with the parameters I can't set by my self, is there any way to interfere and add the definition -DRINSIDE_CALLBACKS to RStudio compile parameters?

Comment: *Of course* you can set the parameters by yourself, it is called editing a source file...